# Grouping Unity NUnit tests?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nunit

I want to group tests like this:

[image]

To get this screenshot I used TestCases, but they don't really apply to my needs.

Obviously I don't want this:

```
[TestCase(TestName = "ShouldDoSomething")]
[TestCase(TestName = "ShouldDoSomethingElse")]
public void OnJoinRoom()
{ ... }
```

I want something like this:

```
[TestGroup("OnJoinRoom")]
public void ShouldDoSomething()
{ ... } 

[TestGroup("OnJoinRoom")]
public void ShouldDoSomethingElse()
{ ... }
```

I don't think using subclasses is an option, as the tests are depending on a SetUp method used in the TestFixture class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NUnit, TestFixtures are used to group tests as well as to provide a common setup. The normal way to provide a common setup across *multiple* TestFixtures is to have a common base class like

```
public class CommonBase
{
    [SetUp]
    public void CommonSetUp() { }
}

[TestFixture]
public class OnJoinRoom : CommonBase { }

[TestFixture]
public class OnLeaveRoom : CommonBase { }
```

Notes:

1. Put all your tests in the derived classes
2. `TestFixture` attribute is optional, of course, but do **not** put it on the base class.
3. Base class may be abstract if you like.